# Changing the file extension of an uploaded image

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm creating a Zend Framework application in which a user can upload a profile image. Acceptable file types are png, jpg and gif. The image ends up getting stored as the user's id + the file extension.

What I'm wondering about is, say a user uploads a png or gif file, is it safe to change the file extension to jpg?

This way all profile images will end up having the same file extension, I'm just not sure if changing the file type like this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if I've never tried to do it, so I can't say if it really works, I think that changing a file extension is not a good idea, since if the web server uses the file extension to determine the content type for the response, the browser could not be able to display the images.
In my opinion you should convert the gif/png images to the jpeg format after the upload, then eventually move, rename or delete the original images, leaving only the converted jpg images in the upload folder.
For example, if you have enabled the [GD extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), you could do something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Convert gif or png image to jpg format
 *  
 * @param string  original image file name
 * @param int     output image quality (0..100) 
 * @return string output jpg file name
 */
function img2jpeg($filename, $quality = 100) {
    if (file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename)) {
        $p = pathinfo($filename);
        $ext = strtolower($p['extension']);
        if ($ext == "jpg") {
            return($filename);
        } else if ($img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename))) {
            $newname = $p['dirname'].'/'.$p['filename'].'.jpg';
            if (imagejpeg($img, $newname, $quality)) {
                imagedestroy($img);
                return($newname);
            } else {
                imagedestroy($img);
                die("Error creating ".$newname."\n");
            }
        }
    }
    die("Error loading ".$filename."\n");
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer, I'll give this a shot :) +1 for the function.